# ListPlot3D not working (tried rescaling and changing ticks)

Tags: plotting

I have a data set where the numbers are really small in the z axis. I've tried rescaling and changing ticks but to no avail it still couldn't work.

```
infXPiSub = {{1, \[Pi], 
0.00011774492358624129785035257490361555966358847284680688716207441\
757433116436`50.}, {2, \[Pi], 
0.00011774492604772028155245129260465774435212311238574400817924470\
175057649612`50.},
{3, \[Pi], 
0.00011774491046335374789625457310372028433858237077972375210195912\
775823501306`50.}, {1, 5, 
0.00011774491099373554742489628810297455767158130281267031103098474\
886792246252`50.},
{2, 5, 0.\
0001177449104625310003375370566049184634491033818658922169305791442794\
8951186`50.}, {3, 5, 
0.00011774491046250785202674988604443695003301413094414157143581341\
485528227308`50.},
{1, 7, 0.\
0001177449106496657864826106106560279060213420252963608531038275373248\
3251952`50.}, {2, 7, 
0.00011774491046250878931449851500575840622231534244831664268642296\
649171677392`50.},
{3, 7, 0.\
0001177449104625078663380797673233746485486515122008882369867488830218\
6540814`50.}, {1, 9, 
0.00011774491075683258058162173779347592649499364890431848951202198\   
350074468181`50.},
{2, 9, 0.\
0001177449104625082809461883381059436676188452153085362763326477971126\
1011769`50.}, {3, 9, 
0.00011774491046250785409944832255231589095790195311617812395045873\
695223786657`50.},
{1, 10, 
0.00011774491052838484386590921119024905966152862889966337900382598\
036230774596`50.}, {2, 10, 
0.00011774491046250794745523422964829818262700545479524573898681501\
174393135983`50.},
{3, 10, 
0.00011774491046250786619856149044340783750001285672896779585901031\
421774962348`50.}}
```

As you can see the values of z axis is really small. Before I get these values, I've set the precision to be 50 digits. Plotting this diagram will return to me an empty plot or sometimes a graph with alot of broken lines. How should I proceed in this case ? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion is to shift the data around 0 with:

```
infXPiSub[[;; , 3]] = infXPiSub[[;; , 3]] - Mean[infXPiSub[[;; , 3]]];
```

You can then plot this with:

```
ListPlot3D[infXPiSub, PlotRange -> All]
```

or

```
ListPointPlot3D[infXPiSub, PlotRange -> All]
```

The axis will be shifted but you can solve that using custom ticks!

Plot without shifting the data around zero:

[image]

Plot shifting the data around zero:

[image]

The output of the second plot looks reasonable: indeed, you can check it doing with the following code

```
infXPiSub[[;; , 3]] = infXPiSub[[;; , 3]] - Mean[infXPiSub[[;; , 3]]];
infXPiSub[[;; , 3]] = Round[infXPiSub[[;; , 3]]*10^12, 0.001];
```

> {{1, [Pi], 11.138}, {2, [Pi], 13.599}, {3, [Pi], -1.985}, {1, 
>     5, -1.455}, {2, 5, -1.986}, {3, 5, -1.986}, {1, 7, -1.799}, {2, 
>     7, -1.986}, {3, 7, -1.986}, {1, 9, -1.692}, {2, 9, -1.986}, {3, 
>     9, -1.986}, {1, 10, -1.92}, {2, 10, -1.986}, {3, 10, -1.986}}

All the points except the first two have very similar values, and that is reflected in the plot.